# Serving static files with Express in S3 or CDN with hask key and sync in deploy

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, deployment, amazon-cloudfront

I need to know how to resolve a concept problem.

I have deployed a Express - Node.js web application in AWS, with a load balancer and some EC2 instances (all working fine). I upload my images to S3 and I want to upload my JS and CSS files to S3 or CDN.

When I deploy a new version I add to my static files (CSS and JS) a hask key query string param like that :

```
<script src="/public/assets/myscript.js?version=20161014"></script>
```

But I want to change to something like this:

```
<script src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/assets/myscript.js?version=20161014"></script>
```

Or better:

```
<script src="https://mycustomname.cloudfront.net/assets/myscript.js?version=20161014"></script>
```

**My question is:**

How can I do a NEW deploy of my expressjs application and upload at the same time to S3 my modifications of the JS and CSS to sync the client code and server code?

**Extra information:** I'm using AWS CodeDeploy Deployments to make deploys of my server code working fine in many EC2 instances, and I have PM2 installed for monitoring, cluster management and other stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you need is querystring cache, i guess this can help:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html